# clean up/delete temp files even after failed chef run

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, temporary-files, resource-cleanup

What i would like is to be able to cleanup temp files I've created even when the chef-run fails. So something like this:

```
begin
  file file_path do
    action :create
  end

#do something

ensure
  file file_path do
    action :delete
  end
end
```

However I can't seem to get this to work. When my `#do something` code breaks, it leaves behind that file that was created.

It seems that `ensure` is evaluated in Compile phase of chef run. So had i put `File.delete(file_path)` instead in the ensure block, it would attempt to delete the file before it was even created (which is in Converge phase when resources, ie. file creation in `begin`, are executed

I know you can also create your own exception handler, but that seems beyond what i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this was any random file I wouldn't be so concerned about cleaning up but because it is a pfx I'm creating temporarily I dont want it lying around after the chef run exits. So as per slack, this is the solution I ended up using by recommendation from @coderanger.

```
Tempfile.create(["cert",".pfx"]) do |f|
  f.write(cert_string)
  f.close
  notifying_block do
    batch "Import cert using certutil" do
      #so stuff
    end
  end
end
```

The file is cleaned up on exit thanks to the automagic of Tempfile
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on Slack, Chef's two-pass model disallows this kind of code. More to the point, the concept of temp files is incompatible with how recipe code works. Just don't bother deleting the file.